# Wobble effect on letters

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, effect

```js
jQuery(function ($) {
  var target = $("#target");
  target.html(target.text().replace(/./g, "<span>$&</span>"));

  setTimeout(runAnimation, 250);

  function runAnimation() {
    var index, spans;

    index = 0;
    spans = target.children();
    doOne();

    function doOne() {
      var span = $(spans[index]);
      if (!$.trim(span.text())) {
        // Skip blanks
        next();
        return;
      }

      // Do this one
      span.css({
          position: "relative",
        })
        .animate(
          {
            top: "-20",
          },
          "fast"
        )
        .animate(
          {
            top: "0",
          },
          "fast",
          function () {
            span.css("position", "");
            next();
          }
        );
    }

    function next() {
      ++index;
      if (index < spans.length) {
        doOne();
      } else {
        setTimeout(runAnimation, 500);
      }
    }
  }
 });
```

```css
.title {
    margin: auto;
    width: 50%;
    color: black;
    text-align: right;
    
}

#target:hover {
    color: rgb(21, 121, 252);
    animation-name: bounce;
    animation-duration: 2s;
}


@keyframes bounce {
  0%   { transform: translateY(0); }
  50%  { transform: translateY(-50px); }
  100% { transform: translateY(0); }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="title">
        <p style="font-size: 45px;"><span id="target">I</span><span id="target">'</span><span id="target">m</span><span>
            </span><span id="target">K</span><span id="target">r</span><span id="target">i</span><span id="target">s</span>
        </p>
    </div>
```

I'm trying to add a wobble effect on each letter but I can't get it to work, I would like the letters to get a bit bigger while hovering them and making the effect run. I'm just learning javascript so I'm not really good at it, the snippet doesn't work and I don't know what's the problem with it.
I found this code for the wobble effect but it's not working, can someone help ? Thanks

Comment: COuld you check  your snippet. It need jquery to be loaded and also it has illegal HTML (ids must be unique).

Comment: Ok thanks, now it's doing something, definitely not wobbling, what do you mean by illegal HTML ?

Comment: Sorry, 'illegal' is a bit strong! I meant thatit is not valid HTML, ids have to be unique.

Comment: So I should change the ID on each letter, but then in the Javascript file I should copy and paste the animation for each new ID ?

Comment: I'd use a class rather than ids

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of manually typing the letters in individual `span` blocks, let JavaScript do it. This will be much more flexible.

Other than that, you do not need to use JavaScript for the animation, do it with CSS instead. That will be much simpler and handleable.

```js
const animatedElements = document.getElementsByClassName('animate');

[...animatedElements].forEach(elm => {
  let text = elm.innerText.split(''); // Split the text into letters and store them in an array
  
  elm.innerText = ''; // Clear the text in the div
  
  // Add the letters one by one, this time inside a <span>
  text.forEach(letter => {
    const span = document.createElement('span');
    span.innerText = letter;
    elm.appendChild(span);
  })
})
```

```css
.animate>span {
  display: inline-block; /* Changing display from the default `inline` to `inline-block` so that `transform` rules apply */
  white-space: break-spaces; /* This is necessary so that the `inline-block` does not collapse the "spaces" */
  transition: transform 200ms ease-in-out;
}

.animate>span:hover {
  transform: translateY(-10px);
}


/* The following rules are just to format the embedded result */
.animate {
  margin: 40px;
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="animate">
  I'm Kris
</div>
```